# Automorphism group of $(\mathbb R_{>0}, \cdot)$

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to find the automorphism group of $(\mathbb R_{>0}, \cdot)$.

What I have so far:

$x \mapsto x^r$ for any $r \in \mathbb R - \{0\}$ is an automorphism.

But I can't think of any others. I have found $|\mathbb R|$ many but because I think $\text{Aut} (\mathbb R_{>0})$ should be much larger than $\mathbb R$ I believe that I didn't find them all.

> Which automorphisms am I missing?

Comment: $\log$ is an isomorphism from $(\mathbb{R}_{>0},\cdot)$ to $(\mathbb{R},+)$, so this is essentially a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115486/what-is-operatornameaut-mathbbr

Answer (score 4):

$(\mathbb R_{>0}, \cdot) \cong (\mathbb R, +)$ via $\log$.

So the question reduces to finding the automorphisms of $(\mathbb R, +)$, that is the [additive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

If you restrict yourself to functions that are either continuous, monotonic on any interval, or bounded on any interval, then the only solutions are the scalings $x\mapsto cx$, which gives you the multiplicative $x\mapsto x^r$.

If you do not impose restrictions on the functions, there are too many and they can be weird. For instance, bijections between two bases of $\mathbb R$ as vector space over $\mathbb Q$ induce additive automorphisms of $\mathbb R$. Note that such bases are uncountable...

Comment: I suggest that the OP did not realize that  by taking logs he would arrive at the Q of additive real functions, which gets asked here about once a week.

Comment: Thank you. Could you include a proof that these permutations of bases are the only automorphisms? I looked at the other threads and a proof is mentioned nowhere.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation#Proof_of_the_existence_of_other_solutions for instance.