# I want to show that $f(x)=x.f(1)$ where $f:R\to R$ is additive.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving that an additive function $f$ is continuous if it is continuous at a single point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93816/proving-that-an-additive-function-f-is-continuous-if-it-is-continuous-at-a-sin)
>   [Solution(s) to $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ (and miscellaneous questions…)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115228/solutions-to-fx-y-fx-fy-and-miscellaneous-questions)

I know that if $f$ is continuous at one point then it is continuous at every point. 
From this i want to show that $f(x)=xf(1).$
Can anybody help me to proving this?

Comment: Start with integer $x$. Then try rational $x$.

Comment: The magic words are "Cauchy functional equation". See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/93816/742) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/115228/742).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINTS:

1. Look at $0$ first: $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)$, so $f(0)=0=0\cdot f(1)$.
2. Use induction to prove that $f(n)=nf(1)$ for every positive integer $n$, and use $f(0)=0$ to show that $f(n)=nf(1)$ for every negative integer as well.
3. $f(1)=f\left(\frac12+\frac12\right)=f\left(\frac13+\frac13+\frac13\right)=\dots\;$.
4. Once you’ve got it for $f\left(\frac1n\right)$, use the idea of (2) to get it for all rationals.
5. **Then** use continuity at a point.