# What is wrong with this proof for linearity?

Tags: linear-transformations

Note: I'm not asking for a solution or a hint relating to the problem itself, I'm just describing it.

> Assume $f: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$ is a continuous function. Furthermore, the equation
>     $$f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$$
>   holds for every $x, y \in \Bbb R^n$. Show that $f$ is a linear function.

So, a friend of mine proved this the following way, and although she did not use the continuity (which makes the proof wrong anyway), I wondered what's so wrong about proving linearity like this in general.

> Assume $s \in \Bbb R$. Then
>     $$f(sx) = f\bigg(\overbrace{x + x + \dotsb + x}^{s\text{ terms}}\bigg)
>           = \overbrace{f(x) + f(x) + \dotsb + f(x)}^{s\text{ terms}}
>           = s f(x)$$

I told her that this couldn't be true since she assumes that $|s| \ge 1$, it wouldn't work out for $- 1 < s < 1$ (or would it?). But is this the only reason? And if it is indeed: Wouldn't that mean that we could indeed prove scalar multiplication (and thus: linearity) if we already showed the additivity of a function and could assume that $|s| \ge 1$?

Comment: More importantly: writing $sx$ and the sum of $s$ terms, all equal to $x$, only works when $s \in \mathbb{N}$! For linearity, you need $f(sx) = sf(x)$ for all $s$ in the field specified (presumably the real numbers). You argument doesn't show, for example, that $f(\sqrt{2}x) = \sqrt{2} f(x)$. And this is where continuity comes in handy!

Comment: Useful: [Continuous and additive implies linear](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/152632/159845)

Comment: Ha, that's interesting! You're right, this would only work for natural numbers, but since the natural numbers aren't a vector space anyway, we couldn't be confronted with cases like this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with N not being a vector space. Your argument is not bad, it's just not "finished". You can extend N to Q with similar reasoning, but not to R (without continuity). I converted my comments into an answer.

Comment: Like I said in the note at the beginning: This question isn't about the task itself, I simply added it pro forma. The question was about why linearity can't be shown in ways like these, and linearity requires vector spaces, and $\Bbb N$ is not a vector space. Thus: One is not able to prove linearity like this in general. That's what you showed me. :-) Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the scalar multiplication, you need $f(sx) = sf(x)$ for all $s \in \Bbb R$. Your argument uses:

> Assume $s \in \Bbb R$. Then
>     $$f(sx) = f\bigg(\overbrace{x + x + \dotsb + x}^{s\text{ terms}}\bigg)
>           = \overbrace{f(x) + f(x) + \dotsb + f(x)}^{s\text{ terms}}
>           = s f(x)$$

But writing $sx$ as the sum of $s$ terms, all equal to $x$, only works for $s \in \mathbb{N}$. You argument doesn't show (yet) why $f(\tfrac{1}{2}x) = \tfrac{1}{2}f(x)$. You can however extend your argument to $s \in \mathbb{Q}$ without using the fact that $f$ is continuous, but then you still don't have, for example, $f(\sqrt{2}x) = \sqrt{2} f(x)$. To then close the 'gap' from rationals to reals, continuity of $f$ comes into the picture.

Related: [Continuous and additive implies linear](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/152632/159845).