# preserving norm map between real normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Suppose $X,Y$ are two real normed spaces,$T:X\to Y$ is the bijective map such that $||Tx+Ty+Tz|| = ||x+y+z||$ for any $x,y,z\in X$.Is $T$ a linear map?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Does there exist a counter-example?

Comment: I don't have an example off the top, but why do you believe this to be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By assumption
$$
\|T(x) + T(y) + T(-x-y)\| = 0,
$$
so 
$$
T(x) + T(y) = -T(-x-y).
$$
In particular, with $x=y=0$ it follows $T(0)=0$, and with $y=0$,
$$
T(x) = -T(-x).
$$
Hence
$$
T(x) + T(y) = -T(-x-y) =T(x+y),
$$
and $T$ is additive. 
Let me show that $T$ is continous. Let $x_n\to x$.
Then
$$
\|T(x) - T(x_n) \| = \|T(x) + T(-x_n)\|=\|x-x_n\|\to0.
$$
So $T$ is continuous and additive, hence it is linear, see [Continuous and additive implies linear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152632/continuous-and-additive-implies-linear)

Comment: don't you also need $T(sy) = sT(y)$ though?

Comment: @user125932 see edit

Comment: I see -- that argument is for functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ but I see that you can adapt it without much difficulty to work in this case